# Parse json string set by controller, in view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

My MVC Controller contains a collection that I want to pass to the view, so I do:

```
// myCollection is a list of objects
var j = new JavaScriptSerializer();
ViewBag.Data = j.Serialize(myCollection);
```

And on the view inside JS

```
var data = $.parseJSON('@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Data)');
```

.. which expands to look something like:

```
var data = $.parseJSON('[{"Value":2,"Fullname":"Value"}]');
```

This works fine, but if my Json string contains a double quote it get's escaped with a backslash, and the parseJson fails, like this:

```
$.parseJSON('[{"Value":2,"Fullname":"Value \" with double quote"}]');
```

How do I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst the following is valid JSON, it doesn't stay like that when the string is in JavaScript as it will unescape first:

```
 '[{"Value":2,"Fullname":"Value \" with double quote"}]'
```

JavaScript will first unescape this to become:

```
 '[{"Value":2,"Fullname":"Value " with double quote"}]'
```

When JSON comes along, it obviously sees an unexpected character since the quote is now looking to end the string. What you need to do is double-quote (`\\"` works) these somehow, whether you want to do it at the JS end or .NET end is probably entirely up to you.

However, there's really no need to parse this using JSON at all and you can just use it as an object literal like so:

```
var data = @Html.Raw(ViewBag.Data);
```

which will convert to:

```
var data = [{"Value":2,"Fullname":"Value \" with double quote"}];
```

.. which is perfectly valid.

Answer (score -2):

why not just create custom function, and call parseJSON inside of it. but replace \" before that?

```
function parseJson(str){
    var temp = str.replace('\"', '"');
    return $.parseJSON(temp);
}
```